# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to send a packet that contains a character array

Tags: c++, udp, packet, go-back-n

Trying to send a packet that contains up to 30 characters along with other identifying information. Here is the constructor.

```
packet::packet(int t, int s, int l, char * d){
type = t;
seqnum = s;
length = l;
data = d;
}
```

For my class we're required to serialize and deserialize via:

```
void packet::serialize(char * spacket){
sprintf (spacket, "%d %d %d %s", type, seqnum, length, data);   
}

void packet::deserialize(char * spacket){
char * itr;
itr = strtok(spacket," ");
char * null_end;

this->type = strtol(itr, &null_end, 10);

itr = strtok(NULL, " ");
this->seqnum = strtol (itr, &null_end, 10);

itr = strtok(NULL, " ");
this->length = strtol (itr, &null_end, 10);

if(this->length == 0){
    data = NULL;
}
else{
    itr = strtok(NULL, " ");    
    for(int i=0; i < this->length; i++){ // copy data into char array
        this->data[i] = itr[i];
    }
  }
}
```

This client code causes my server.exe to have a segmentation fault:

```
char sendPayload[512];
char receivePayload[512];
char sendBuffer[30] = {'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
int receivedPacketType = 0;
int sendPacket;
int receivePacket;

bzero(receivePayload, 512);
bzero(sendPayload, 512);

for (int iterator = 0; iterator < 8; iterator++)
{
    //Setting up sendPayload for sending.
    packet sendpckt(1, iterator, strlen(sendBuffer), sendBuffer);
    sendpckt.serialize((char*)sendPayload);

    //Datagram send to emulator.
    sendPacket = sendto(sendSocket, &sendPayload, sizeof(sendPayload), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendSocketStruct, sendSocketLen);

    //Datagram wait on receive from emulator.
    receivePacket = recvfrom(receiveSocket, &receivePayload, sizeof(sendPayload), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&receiveSocketStruct, &receiveSocketLen);

    //Setting up packet for receivePayload.
    packet recvpckt(0,0,0,NULL);
    recvpckt.deserialize((char*)receivePayload);
    recvpckt.printContents();

    bzero(receivePayload, 512);
    bzero(receivePayload, 512);

}
```

Here is the server side receiving code:

```
char receivePayload[512];
char sendPayload[512];
int expectedSeqNum = 0;
int receivedPacketType = 0;
int receivedPacketSeqNum = 0;
int receivedPacketLength = 0;
char receivedPacketData[512];
int receivePacket;
int sendPacket;
std:string finalText;

bzero(receivePayload, 512);
bzero(sendPayload, 512);

do
{
    receivePacket = recvfrom(receiveSocket, &receivePayload, sizeof(receivePayload), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&receiveSocketStruct, &receiveSocketLen);
    packet recvpckt(0, 0, 0, NULL);
    recvpckt.deserialize((char*)receivePayload);
    receivedPacketType = recvpckt.getType();
    receivedPacketSeqNum = recvpckt.getSeqNum();
    receivedPacketLength = recvpckt.getLength();
    bzero(receivePayload, 512);
    recvpckt.printContents();

    if (receivedPacketType == 3)
    {
        break;
    }

    /*
    if (receivedPacketType == 1)
    {
        *receivedPacketData = *recvpckt->getData();
        printf("%s\n", receivedPacketData);
    }
    */

    if (receivedPacketSeqNum == expectedSeqNum)
    {
        packet sendpckt(0, expectedSeqNum, 0, NULL);
        sendpckt.serialize((char*)sendPayload);
        sendPacket = sendto(sendSocket, &sendPayload, sizeof(sendPayload), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendSocketStruct, sendSocketLen);
        bzero(sendPayload, 512);
        expectedSeqNum = expectedSeqNum + 1;
        if (expectedSeqNum > 7)
        {
            expectedSeqNum = 0;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        packet sendpckt(0, expectedSeqNum, 0, NULL);
        sendpckt.serialize((char*)sendPayload);
        sendPacket = sendto(sendSocket, &sendPayload, sizeof(sendPayload), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendSocketStruct, sendSocketLen);
        bzero(sendPayload, 512);
    }

} while (1);
```

If I null the contents of the data in the packet and set the length to 0, packets get transferred perfectly fine. As soon as I try to increase the length of the packet and give it a string the server experiences a segmentation fault.

What am I missing here? I feel like I'm making my buffers too big or maybe I'm pointing or referencing something incorrectly.

Comment: Is this C code? It sure looks like it.

Comment: C++, yes. New user, how do I go about denoting this for everyone upfront?

Comment: Nervermind, edited the title.

Comment: Generally, it is a good idea to post compilable code (please read about how to create an MCVE — [MCVE]).  You have `std:string finalText;` which doesn't compile.  You can't attach labels to variable definitions, AFAIK (certainly not in C), and namespaces use double colons.

Comment: Gotcha, made changes to tags and title. I have it on my machine as a .cpp file if that makes any difference.

Comment: @tadman: There are definitely C++-only aspects, like the scope operator `::` and the use of 'undeclared variable' `this` in the code.  That marks it unequivocally as C++ — albeit C++ with a C-ish flavour.

Comment: Yeah, so is packet a class? We have a winner. C++ it is.

Comment: @ApolloSoftware This is so C flavoured I didn't even notice that. This is in dire need of some Standard Library love.

Comment: @tadman, agreed!

Comment: Also @AustinHeath you really should put some better err handling in your deserialize method, especially with all the casting you're doing.

Comment: Haha yeah, my professor wrote that method. I'll let him know haha. @ApolloSoftware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your receive packet (`recvpckt`) like this:

```
packet recvpckt(0, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Which makes the `data` member NULL.

Then you call `recvpckt.deserialize`, which writes to the uninitialized `data` array. You need to have a memory allocation somewhere (e.g. in `recvpckt.deserialize`), or else pass the address of an array to the `recvpckt` constructor to write the data into.

This kind of problem is best solved with the use of a debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much! My professor warned us that the char * data field of the packet needed to be initialized before trying to deserialize data into it, however I didn't completely understand what that meant. Thank you so much for pointing that out; I am now able to pass zero terminated strings to the server. @samgak